# a question discerning space complexity from newbie

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o, space-complexity

Can someone explain why the space complexity of this algo is O(n) and not O(1)?

```
function subtotals(array) {
    var subtotalArray = Array(array.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var subtotal = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            subtotal += array[j];
        }
        subtotalArray[i] = subtotal;
    }
    return subtotalArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new element in `subtotalArray` for every item in the `array` parameter. So if you have 1000 items in the input array, the output array will require a certain amount of memory, let's say X. If you have 100,000 items in the input array, the output array will require 100* X memory, or thereabouts.

(There's also the `subtotal` number that gets created on every iteration)